# What's wrong with given query regarding displaying ad counters for categories?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, count

I have a asp.net website where users can put ads. In there I want to display ad counters for each category. I am using MYSQL DB.

To do that currently I am using this query

```
    SELECT 
    type.`type_id_pk`,
    type.`name`,
    COUNT(head.`header_id_pk`) AS `count` 
  FROM
    `testdb`.`type` AS `type` 
    LEFT JOIN `header` AS head 
      ON head.`type_id_fk` = type.`type_id_pk` 
  GROUP BY type.`type_id_pk` 
  ORDER BY `name` ASC ;
```

above query works fine. But in my site I separate ads in to countries. So I want to display ad counters specifically for a country. To do that I modified above query to like this

```
        SELECT 
        type.`type_id_pk`,
        type.`name`,
        COUNT(head.`header_id_pk`) AS `count` 
      FROM
        `testdb`.`type` AS `type` 
        LEFT JOIN `header` AS head 
          ON head.`type_id_fk` = type.`type_id_pk` 
  WHERE head.`country_id_fk` = _country_id 
      GROUP BY type.`type_id_pk` 
      ORDER BY `name` ASC ;
```

_country_id is the place where I insert specific country id. So from above query it only returns rows which have ads. If there is no ad that category is not displaying. **So I want to display all the categories along with their counters for a specific country.( including 0 ad categories)** .So whats wrong with the above query? ( Please consider query efficiency. )

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your code seems to enforce an inner join, so that null results are excluded. You might try a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include null results, and lighten the restriction in the `WHERE` clause that weeds out null results.

```
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `header` AS head 
          ON head.`type_id_fk` = type.`type_id_pk` 
  WHERE head.`country_id_fk` = _country_id OR head.`country_id_fk` IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried this. But then if I give a country id which doesn't have ads then category that already have ads in another country will not displaying in the list ( Category is hiding ).

Comment: Ducking out of this question, but I wanted to show this tool for you http://sqlfiddle.com/ it is very useful for questions that are complicated, so SO people can just toy with the code you have written already and see exactly what results you want.